# MongoDB in PHP using aggregate to group by _id is null not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use this MongoDB command and filter, its dosen work when i translate it to PHP, hope there are one there can help me to explain why its not working?

**MongoDB syntax:**

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { 'Store.Title': { $regex: 'apc', $options: 'gi' } } },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
);
```

**Output from MongoDB:**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : 774.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

**PHP Filter array:**

```
[
    [
        '$match' => [
            'Store.Title' => ['$regex' => 'apc', '$options' => 'gi']
        ]
    ],[
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => 'null',
            'count' => [ '$sum' => 1 ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Output from PHP:**

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

i hope there are simple explaining on this issue thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`MongoRegex`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php)** object:

```
$search = "apc";
$where = array('Store.Title' => array('$regex' => new MongoRegex("/^$search/gi")));
// $where = array('Store.Title' => array('$regex' => new MongoRegex("/".$search."/gi")));

[
    [ '$match' => $where ],
    [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => 'null',
            'count' => [ '$sum' => 1 ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: did you try the other `$where` array? `$where = array('Store.Title' => array('$regex' => new MongoRegex("/".$search."/gi")));`

Comment: Hmm now my jQuery give me "An error occurred trying to load the resource" and block my respons data, its only happen when i use the MongoRegex function but if i run it outsite the jQuery i get the right data back now ( Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => null [count] => 673 ) ) [ok] => 1 ) )

Comment: the last issue, is jquery.ajax has none timeout now before i have set a timeout on it there crash everything, :) thanks a lot for helping

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser No worries, glad that worked out well for you in the end :-)