# MongoDB in PHP does not recognize aggregations

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working with the [new](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-query.construct.php) PHP mongoDB driver that uses a filter array (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675015/mongodb-in-php-using-aggregate-to-group-by-id-is-null-not-working)). My PHP code and filter array is

```
require '/etc/php5/cli/vendor/autoload.php'; // load Composer things
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter = 
[
  '$match' => [
    'title' => 'Title1'
  ]
];
```

However, whenever I use $match or any other aggregation, I get the error:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException' with message 'unknown top level operator: $match'`

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to be using [`aggregate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php). The error looks like you are trying to use [`find()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

Comment: The aggregate() and find() syntax is for the deprecated driver. The [new driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-query.construct.php) doesn't have MongoCollection, it uses MongoDB\Driver\Query in which you pass in a filter array.